# Electromagnetic waves, displacement currents and capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves

Question:

> Q. A parallel-plate capacitor having plate-area $A$ and plate separation $d$ is joined to a battery of emf $E$ & and internal resistance $R$ at $t=0$. Consider a plane surface of area
>   $A/2$, parallel to the plates and situated symmetrically between them. Define
>   displacement resistance 
>                    $$R_{d}=\frac{V}{i_{d}}$$
>   Of the space between the plates where $V$ is the potential difference between the plates and id is the displacement current. Show that $R_d$ varies with time as 
>   $$
> R_{d}=R\left(e^{t / \tau}-1\right)
> $$

Here’s the popular and unclear solution:-

> \begin{aligned} \mathrm{E} &=\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} \mathrm{A}}(\text { Electric field }) \\ \phi &=\mathrm{E} \cdot \mathrm{A}=\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} \mathrm{A}} \frac{\mathrm{A}}{2}=\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} 2} \\ \mathrm{i}_{0} &=\epsilon_{0} \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_{\mathrm{E}}}{\mathrm{dt}}=\epsilon_{0} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} 2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{Q}}{\mathrm{dt}}\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\left(\mathrm{E} \mathrm{C} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{t} / \mathrm{RC}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{E} \mathrm{C}-\frac{1}{\mathrm{RC}} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{t} / \mathrm{RC}}=\frac{-\mathrm{E}}{2 \mathrm{R}} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-\mathrm{td}}{\mathrm{RE}_{0} \lambda}} \\ \phi &=\mathrm{E} \cdot \mathrm{A}=\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} \mathrm{A}} \frac{\mathrm{A}}{2}=\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} 2} \\ i_{0} &=\epsilon_{0} \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_{\mathrm{E}}}{\mathrm{dt}}=\epsilon_{0} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0} 2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{dQ}}{\mathrm{dt}}\right) \end{aligned}

[combined from both the answers to both the questions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the emf.Then $$V=U(1-e^{-t/ \tau})$$
With $\tau=RC$.
 Rewriting this expression with factor $e^{-t/\tau}$ we obtain: 
$$V=U e^{-t/\tau}(e^{t/\tau}-1)$$
Let us show that the term $U e^{-t/\tau}$ is indeed of the form $Ri_{d}$.
$$i_{d}=A \epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$$
Now
$$ E= q/ (\epsilon_{0}A) =\frac{UC}{\epsilon_{0}A}(1- e^{-t/\tau})$$
$$A\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} =\frac{UC}{\tau}e^{-t/ \tau}$$
Finally: 
$$Ri_{d}=U\frac{RC}{\tau }e^{-t\tau}=Ue^{-t/ \tau}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I think you got it spot on!